# How to center a div inside a div?

Tags: html, css

my HTML is as below:

```
  <div id="background_div">
    <img id="background_img" src="images/background.jpg" alt="dont matter">
    <i class="material-icons">perm_identity</i>
    <div id="dropdown">
      <ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#!">one<span class="badge">1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">two<span class="new badge">1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a class="btn dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown2">Select Service<i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I changed the syntax to have the div id "dropdown" inside div id "background_div" (child/parent) because I thought it may help me centre using some sort relative CSS function. I originally had the two divs as siblings... Basically, all i'm trying to achieve is getting the dropdown div smack bang in the middle of the background_div . Be nice to do it in a responsive way too.

Can anyone please provide some CSS script to help me achieve?

Thank you!

Comment: You see, there's a good reference here.. https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: are you trying to center it vertically or horizontally?

Comment: @cup_of trying to both vertically and horizontally center. I made use of text-align center for parent div, but that just centered horizontal - any ideas for vertical? cheers !

Answer (score 0):

This CSS makes use of [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
#background_div {
  display: flex;
}

#dropdown {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Careful with this. Flexbox is relatively new and subject to bugs. Research your browser support before utilizing.

Comment: It's a fair warning, but Flexbox has been a while at this point. Plus, it does have great support in major browsers. For a basic use case like this, anyway, there should be no issues

Answer (score 0):

You can add `text-align: center;` to the css style of `#background_div`, but then EVERYTHING inside of `#background_div` will be centered. If you only want certain parts to be centered, wrap those parts in a `<span>` tag, with the class `centered`, so `<span class="centered">`. Then in your css, add in

```
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Now you can add a `<span class="centered">` around anything that you want to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

my favorite method to vertically center something is to do:

```
/* the div you want centered inside another div*/

#dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* set the parent div to position relative */

#background_div {
    position: relative;
}
```

This will probably mess up your horizontal center if you are using text-align center. In that case add this to your css

```
width: 100px; /* give it any width that fits */)
margin: 0 auto;
```

so your final code will look like:

```
#dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#background_div {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail!!!

Comment: np, did this work for u?

Comment: Hi, sort of (thank you), but something was additionally missing - using materialize framework so had to go through styling in dev tools to find out that line-height and div height were different - after I made the same, all the positioning code outlined above worked! Cheers